# Why on a complete metric spaces that are Polish spaces we can define probability measures?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, polish-spaces

I have a slight background on probability measures and Polish spaces.

I know that a Polish space is a separable completely metrizable topological space.
In the lecture notes I am following the author says:

"Since the metric space $(G,d)$ is a Polish space, we may consider the set of probability measures on $G$ denoted by $\mathcal{P}(G)$"

Comment: What's the source? You don't need $G$ to be Polish to consider probability measures on $G$, but I suspect that this will be needed for something else the author wants to do later (for example over a Polish space every Borel measure is tight and weak convergence of measures is the same as convergence in the Prokhorov metric on $\mathcal P(G)$ )

Comment: He will probably need it for something else later on, but I do not know yet, the notes discuss the Benjamini-Schramm convergence of unrooted finite graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always consider the set of (Borel) probability measures on any space $X$. But for Polish spaces it's a nice space with a lot of structure, see Kechris' book (Classical Descriptive Set Theory), p. 109 and onwards for more details. It is Polish and if $X$ is compact then so is $\mathcal{P}(X)$ etc. There is a nice description of convergence of measures as well.